# Flying div’s in an other div (not over the whole page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like the div’s move in an other div. Now they are flying over the whole page.

What should I change in the code to make this work?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.balloon').each(animateDiv);
});

function makeNewPosition() {

  // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
  var h = $(window).height() - 50;
  var w = $(window).width() - 50;

  var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
  var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

  return [nh, nw];

}

function animateDiv() {
  var el = $(this);
  var newq = makeNewPosition();
  var oldq = $(el).offset();
  var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

  $(el).animate({
    top: newq[0],
    left: newq[1]
  }, speed, function() {
    animateDiv.apply(this);
  });

};


function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

  var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
  var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

  var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

  var speedModifier = .4;

  var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);

  return speed;

}
```

```css
.balloon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Create a New Pen</title>

  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


</head>

<body>
  <div class='balloon'></div>
  <div class='balloon'></div>
  <div class='balloon'></div>

  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>

  <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap a div around them, eg `.container`, set the CSS values for it, and then change:

```
// Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
var h = $(window).height() - 50;
var w = $(window).width() - 50;
```

for

```
// Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
var h = $('.container').height() - 50;
var w = $('.container').width() - 50;
```

And there goes:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.balloon').each(animateDiv);
});

function makeNewPosition(){
    
    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    var h = $('.container').height() - 50;
    var w = $('.container').width() - 50;
    
    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
    
    return [nh,nw];    
    
}

function animateDiv(){
  var el = $(this);
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    var oldq = $(el).offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);
    
    $(el).animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
      animateDiv.apply(this);        
    });
    
};


function calcSpeed(prev, next) {
    
    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);
    
    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;
    
    var speedModifier = .4;

    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest/speedModifier);

    return speed;

}
```

```css
.container {
position:relative;
width:400px;
height:200px;
border: solid 1px;
margin: 50px auto 1000px auto;
}

.balloon {
width: 50px;
height:50px;
background-color:red;
position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Create a New Pen</title>
  
  
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>
<div class='container'>
  <div class='balloon'></div>
  <div class='balloon'></div>
  <div class='balloon'></div>
</div>

  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>

    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you Mario!
It looks like it works fine. But when you scroll, the balloons jumps out the div. So they keep visible while scrolling. I would like them to stay in the div. (hopefully you understand what I mean).

Comment: You're welcome @DonaldRoos ! I see what you mean, take a look at my code, I added a margin to be able to scroll down in the fiddle and check that it works. I forgot to mention in that the css for the balloons you must change ´position:fixed´ for ´position:absolute´, that's the reason why the balloons keep visible.

Answer (score 1):

Create a div and add a height and width in the css. Then instead of window, use the class that you gave the div for the `.height()` and `.width()` parts.

You don't have to put the balloons in the div in the html, but I did just cuz.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.balloon').each(animateDiv);
});

function makeNewPosition(){
    
    // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
    var h = $('.sky').height() - 50;
    var w = $('.sky').width() - 50;
    
    var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
    var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
    
    return [nh,nw];    
    
}

function animateDiv(){
  var el = $(this);
    var newq = makeNewPosition();
    var oldq = $(el).offset();
    var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);
    
    $(el).animate({ top: newq[0], left: newq[1] }, speed, function(){
      animateDiv.apply(this);        
    });
    
};


function calcSpeed(prev, next) {
    
    var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
    var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);
    
    var greatest = x > y ? x : y;
    
    var speedModifier = .4;

    var speed = Math.ceil(greatest/speedModifier);

    return speed;

}
```

```css
.balloon {
width: 50px;
height:50px;
background-color:red;
position:fixed;
    
}
.sky{
  width:100%;
  height:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Create a New Pen</title>
  
  
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'>

      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>
<div class="sky">

</div><div class='balloon'></div>
<div class='balloon'></div>
<div class='balloon'></div>
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>

    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Paige,
It looks like it works fine. But when you scroll, the balloons jumps out the div. So they keep visible while scrolling. I would like them to stay in the div. (hopefully you understand what I mean).

Answer (score 0):

I have removed few things. Just follow the below code. change the CND jquery request to https

`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.balloon').each(animateDiv);
});

function makeNewPosition() {

  // Get viewport dimensions (remove the dimension of the div)
  var h = $(window).height() - 50;
  var w = $(window).width() - 50;

  var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
  var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);

  return [nh, nw];

}

function animateDiv() {
  var el = $(this);
  var newq = makeNewPosition();
  var oldq = $(el).offset();
  var speed = calcSpeed([oldq.top, oldq.left], newq);

  $(el).animate({
    top: newq[0],
    left: newq[1]
  }, speed, function() {
    animateDiv.apply(this);
  });

};


function calcSpeed(prev, next) {

  var x = Math.abs(prev[1] - next[1]);
  var y = Math.abs(prev[0] - next[0]);

  var greatest = x > y ? x : y;

  var speedModifier = .4;

  var speed = Math.ceil(greatest / speedModifier);

  return speed;

}
```

```css
.balloon {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Create a New Pen</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'>
</head>

<body>
  <div class='balloon'></div>
  <div class='balloon'></div>
  <div class='balloon'></div>

  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>


</body>

</html>
```